# What is the functional difference between `loginctl terminate-session` `loginctl kill-session` and `systemctl stop`

Tags: systemd

I'm having trouble sussing out the differences between these commands, especially around using them with `session-c###.scope` units. I've tried looking at the man page, and looking through the code a bit but some questions remain.

The man page suggests `loginctl kill-session` sends a signal to one or all processes in a session. So how is this different from `loginctl terminate-session`? The man page suggests

> This kills all processes of the session and deallocates all resources attached to the session.

but is this much different from `kill-session -s SIGKILL`?

The problem I'm facing is after doing something like `loginctl kill-session c###`, the session no longer appears for the user in `loginctl session-status` or `list-sessions`, but `systemctl status session-c###.scope` will show it as abandoned, and the processes appear to remain according to `ps`. I wonder if `loginctl terminate-session` would have been better, or even `systemctl stop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loginctl kill-session [--signal=]` has exactly the same effect as `systemctl kill` – both end up calling systemd's KillUnit(signal) via D-Bus on the .scope unit object. (Note that both default to sending a SIGTERM, *not* SIGKILL.)

Similarly, `loginctl terminate-session` has mostly the same effect as `systemctl stop`, both commands will call systemd's StopUnit() via D-Bus. (However, loginctl will explicitly mark the .scope as "abandoned" before trying to stop it, causing systemd to log about any leftover processes.)

A small difference in both cases is that the calls made by loginctl are proxied through the `logind` daemon, which applies different polkit authorization rules than a direct call to systemd would. (For example, normally non-root users cannot call systemd directly.)